# Convert keras model to quantized tflite lost precision

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert my keras model into tflite quantized model so that I can run my model on coral TPU, but the output of my keras model and tflite model are significantly different.

The red points are quantized tflite model output, and blue points are original keras model output.

[image]

Here is my code to convert keras model to quantized tflite model :

```
quant = True
gc.collect()
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pathlib
print(tf.__version__)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
if quant:
    print("Converting quant....")
    sample_size = 200
    rdm_idx = np.random.choice(range(len(X_test)),sample_size)
    rep_data = tf.cast(X_train[rdm_idx], tf.float32) / 255.0
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(rep_data).batch(1)

    def representative_data_gen():
        for input_value in dataset.take(sample_size):
            yield [input_value]

    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
    converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
    tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()
    open("MaskedLandMarkDetction_MobileNetV2_quant_fromKeras_v5.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model_quant)

    print("Write quantization tflite done.")
else:
    print("Converting normal....")
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("MaskedLandMarkDetction_MobileNetV2_fromKeras.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
    print("Write tflite done.")
```

`X_train` is my training data, and I will scale input images value from 0 to 1 by divided `255.`, so I do the same in `representative_data_gen` functions.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

The tensorflow version I used is gpu 2.2.0

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the usage of the api is correct. Not all models are guaranteed to get good accuracy with post training quantization. For example, tasks that require more precision or small models may suffer more loss.

For these more difficult tasks we recommend using quantization aware training, which is available for keras models: https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training.

Comment: I tried, but it through an error to me : ValueError: Only some Keras activations under `tf.keras.activations` are supported. For other activations, use `Quantizer` directly, and update layer config using `QuantizeConfig`.

Comment: The model I use is less built-in model "MobileNetV2" in to 2.2.0.